# Django Media files "Could not load image" with 200 status response

Tags: django, django-models

I'm slightly new to Django and I'm having an issue with the ImageField field type in development environment. I'm able to upload images through the admin panel, and I have them going to my media folder location locally. But they will not render in the DOM from Django.

I'm running Django 2.1.7 and have Pillow 5.4.1 installed

My media folder is located in my base directory (same level as my manage.py file), and has a sub-directory of series (as created by my model), with all of the correct images I uploaded through the admin panel.

Within my template .html file, I am trying to load the image with:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{{ s.cardImage.url }}">
```

And I get a 200 status response in the terminal, but the image does not render and when I inspect the image, it says "Could not load image". If I simply output {{ s.cardImage.url }} within my template, I get this path: /media/series/IMG_5776.PNG.
So I'm inclined to think that my views are correct and I'm querying the correct object from my database.

When I uploaded the image within the Admin panel, this is what it looks like: [Admin Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz9at.png)

If I click on that link within the admin panel (from picture above) series/IMG_5776.PNG, it takes me to this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/series/IMG_5776.PNG and the DOM is blank (with a 200 status code returning from my development server).

This is where I am stumped. I've done a lot of research and I feel like I have everything properly set-up. Does anyone know what could possibly be going wrong? Help is greatly appreciated.

Relevant Settings:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Model:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cardImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='series', default='default.jpg')
```

Terminal Log:

```
"GET /media/series/IMG_5776.PNG HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Base urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at it in other browsers?

Comment: @aris Yes, I've tried it in multiple different browsers. Chrome/incognito chrome, Firefox, Firefox developer, Edge. All the same result

Comment: Have you inspected the images in the folder via the file browser?

Comment: Yes, the images that I'm trying to render are in the media folder within my file browser. I've tried a number of different images, all the same result.

Comment: Why `{% load static %}` when you are using media path.

Comment: The load static template tag loads the static files when a template is rendered. These can be things like a .css file, or JavaScript files. Separate from media and unrelated, in my understanding.

Comment: @Brady can you see in the browser's network tab what content type is being returned for the image? In the response headers you should see `Content-Type: image/png`

Comment: It's hard to see how this could be a Django issue if the images are being uploaded correctly and are being served with a 200 response. Do you have any content blockers or security software running at the system level that might be interfering with the loading of images? It sounds like your browsers will not load the images. If you curl that URL from the command line do you get the image?